# Using hyphens to connect words to the same meaning (conjunction?)

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I had a debate at work, over which thing would be considered the most correct way of writing the following (English):

"The company offers engineering, retail and architectural services"

or

"The company offers engineering-, retail- and architectural services"

I am from Denmark, and in Danish we use the second approach which connects

Comment: The suspended hyphens would only make sense if you used *architectural-services*. But you didn't. You can't suspend the use of a hyphen and then never follow through with its use in the final phrase.

Comment: The second approach is wrong. Normal adjectives do not require hyphenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preposition almost any reasonable number of adjectives that are just regular adjectives. There is no need for hyphens:

"The company offers engineering, retail and architectural services"

However, hyphenation happens like this:

> Some trees bear fruit and others bear nuts.
>
> Becomes: **fruit- and nut-bearing** trees.
>
> Very often, there are two or three nouns connected to the same verb.
>   ***This calls for hyphenation in the adjectival form to avoid repetition.***

It is understood that what follows the first hyphen is implied.  It is the same as the gerund in the second, but it is left out. When spoken (as in when someone reads a text, their intonation will carry this meaning.)

An example with three hyphens:

> Ideas based on tradition, culture and history
>
> tradition-, culture- and history-based ideas.

Or a more technical example:

> a generator can be powered by wind, electricity or water
>
> wind-, electricity and water-powered generators

To be noted: how it is the verb that structures the hyphenation.

Answer (score 1):

In English, it is definitely the former (the version without the hyphens) that is correct; the latter is not. *Engineering* and *retail* are here complete, stand-alone words; the use of hyphens would wrongly imply that they are prefixes in some compounds that are either hyphenated or spelled closed.

It would be correct to use hyphens in, for example, 'The vegetables should be neither under- nor overcooked' or 'Both pre- and post-production took a long time'; this is because in the first example *under-* stands for *undercooked*, and in the second *pre-* stands for *pre-production*.

Comment: My only issue here is that overcook and undercook are words in their own right. That's a special case,I'd say.